# Passing $routeParams id value into second controller, when first controller stop displaying data

Tags: html, angularjs

I have two controllers which display multiple categories and subcategories.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
              $routeProvider. 


           when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'xyz/category.html',
                controller: 'myCtrl'
            }).

            when('/subcategory/:id', {
                templateUrl: 'xyz/subcategory.html',  
                controller: 'subcategoryCtrl'                
            }).

            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    });
```

**Controller 1**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
alert("myCtrl");
  $http.get("http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/categories?apiKey=anzdbv4h3y5tfk2quyngxpsa&format=json")
  .success(function (response) {$scope.sample = response.categories;

  });
});
```

**Controller 2**

```
app.controller('subcategoryCtrl', function($scope,$routeParams,$http) {

console.log("http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/categories(id="+$routeParams.id+")?apiKey=anzdbv4h3y5tfk2quyngxpsa&format=json")
 $http.get("http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/categories(id="+$routeParams.id+")?apiKey=anzdbv4h3y5tfk2quyngxpsa&format=json")
  .success(function (response) { 
var datalen=JSON.stringify(response.categories[0].subCategories.length);
alert(datalen);
    if(datalen == "0" ){
  alert("no data");
  var idvalue = $routeParams.id;
  alert(idvalue);
}
else{

  $scope.subproduct = response.categories[0].subCategories;

}
 // alert("response.categories[0].subCategories-->"+response.categories[0].subCategories);
  });
});
```

And views file of both controller are as:

**Category View **

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Products</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="product in sample">
    <td>
    <a href="#/subcategory/{{$index=product.id}}">
    {{product.name}}
    </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Subcategory View**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>subcategory </th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="subcategory in subproduct">
    <td>
     <a href="#/subcategory/{{$index=subcategory.id}}">
    {{subcategory.name}}
    </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It fetches all subcategories but i want to fetch the products when subcategory lenght become 0 as specify in 2nd controller from this api:

```
**http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/products(categoryPath.id="Id_value")?apiKey=anzdbv4h3y5tfk2quyngxpsa&page=1&format=json**
```

When the stringifi length become zero i want to use current routepamams id to access this id into another controller then i can access my product list by passing value of routeparams id into products controller and fetch ??
How i can access the id??

Comment: Don't use `success` use `then`. Use a service to make `$http` requests. And don't use `$rootScope`, make a service that has getters and setters for your project. Thats how you share your data in Angular.

Comment: $http request for products

Comment: @OZ_ I used the comment section like it should be, I suggested improvements not an answer... If more people followed best practice and didn't use depreciated things we'd all have a much easier time. So I think you'll find that your comment was a waste.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not in controller, but in View.
What do you expect to see here?

```
<a href="#/subcategory/{{$index=subcategory.id}}">
```

Check your links in browser debugger/console. Change it to

```
<a href="#/subcategory/{{subcategory.id}}">
```